# AlarmManager Android Every Day

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

I'm trying to make a Schedule.

It should run every day at 1pm or 2pm...

At the moment I can only make it run Every 10Sec or 10min...

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, MyAlarmService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

Toast.makeText(AndroidAlarmService.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 102):

This code will run the Intent each day on 1 PM or 2 PM

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13); // For 1 PM or 2 PM
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
            new Intent(context, MyClass.class),PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

Comment: You may want to add calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1); to avoid firing the alarm immediately.

Comment: You could also add calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); to be more precise :)

Comment: Would this also run when the application goes background/closed/paused?

Comment: @MarioGalván yes, until the alarm is cancelled, or the device is rebooted and this code doesn't execute again

Comment: @JDJ Hmmm I think that won't help much to the alarm's precision, moreover after latest modifications to AlarmManager behavior introduced in KitKat

Comment: How we can give interval of a month since not every month is of 30 days.

Comment: And where should this code go? `MainActivity`? When should this be executed? I'm missing the context here.

Comment: Mine appears everytime i load the app even though i set a time of day... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40812244/how-to-set-one-alarm-or-multiple-alarms-once-in-notification-and-not-repeat-if

Comment: i have tried it and it works fine but after some days it just stop and app stops firing BroadcastReceiver does any one you know what is going on

Comment: @ZubairAkber did you got any solution?

Comment: No @SaeedJassani i didn't, if you find any kindly share it

Answer (score -10):

This will alarm every day.

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY , pendingIntent);
```

Comment: `set()` will only fire once. `setRepeating()` will fire every day.

Comment: -1 This code is not correct (at least as of SDK 2.1). AlarmManager.setRepeating accepts 4 parameters, not 3.