# Start Android service process at specific time?

Tags: android, android-service

i currently making an app that checking file change/modification on android SD memory.
this checking file process is running on a background service..
the thing is i don't want this service execute this process all the time
i want the process running on user specified time.
how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make you task run By the AlarmManager, see this question: [AlarmManager Android Every Day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562757/alarmmanager-android-every-day)

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this with the AlarmManager. See [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

This was successful in this post:
[Using Alarmmanager to start a service at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052149/using-alarmmanager-to-start-a-service-at-specific-time)