# Set an alarm at specific date and time

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to set an alarm in my application. Whenever the alarm is started, an `AlertDialog` is shown to the user.

I have created two activities:

- `ActivityA` is the one in charge of setting the alarm
- `ActivityB`is the one in charge of showing the `AlertDialog` window to the user

**`ActivityA`: setting the alarm**

The alarm date is stored in the variable `alarmDate` of type `GregorianCalendar`. I created the alarm using the following code (following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562757/alarmmanager-android-every-day)):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra(ActivityB.ALARM_MESSAGE, message);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmDate.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

**`ActivityB`: handling the request**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(ALARM_MESSAGE);      
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
                       .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()...)
                       .create();
    dialog.show();
    finish();
}
```

**The problem**

I have encountered a problem: `ActivityB` is not able to capture the intent. Thus, I think that it is never created and I am missing something on how to start it.

Moreover, I don't think this is the most desirable solution, since I need the alarm to show the `AlertDialog` window also in case the application is not running.

Any hint on how to solve these problems?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `PendingIntent.getService` but should [getActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

**UPD**
About AlertDialog, you could use transparent activity and still open AlertDialog.

Comment: I have tried switching with this second method, but it seems again mute, unfortunately. Maybe handling the thing in the onCreate method is wrong?

Comment: Why you call `finish` onCreate?

Comment: All the code that the activity has to execute is in the onCreate method. Apart from this, I tried to debug the code: it never happens that the execution reaches that method.

Comment: Well, we are just making assumptions here. It is hard to say. Did you define activities in android manifest? How do you know it never reaches onCreate of the activity?