# Which approach to use to make a daily notification?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I want my app to do is: Once a day check if the user have written a note, If not, add a notification to the statusbar, reminding the user to start the app, and write a note.

Can I use the alarm-manager or do I have to use a Service for this? Do anyone know where to find a good tutorial on this, or have some example code ?

Comment: Here's a **downloadable** example for scheduling alarms which will **survive reboots**: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [AlarmManager Android Every Day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562757/alarmmanager-android-every-day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager`. Permanently running a Service just for scheduling a regular task would be an overkill.

Have a look at this question, for example: [AlarmManager Android Every Day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562757/alarmmanager-android-every-day)

Comment: What if the user restart its phone, will the alarms still be running?

Comment: There is one problem with AlarmManager in KitKat OS can shift alarms, so if you need notification to be fired at exact time it's better to implement Sevice

Comment: Its not required to be at an exact time...Just sometime in the day, like between 6pm and 11pm is accurat enough.

Comment: @Chaosit even on KitKat, I'd discourage using a Service, but simply using `AlarmManager.setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)` in case such high accuracy is needed.

Comment: By the way, it won't work after restart without rescheduling.