# Android Calling method / function every hour

Tags: android, time, timer, alarmmanager, schedule

I have service app that will call method every hour but using loop and that is can't be every hour correctly ( 1:00 or 2:00 or 3:00 etc) if i want correctly, i must start service at 1:00 or 2:00 or any like that, so is there some method to calling method / function at every hour.. ? exactly every 1:00 or 2:00 or n:00 o'clock ?

Sorry bad english...

Comment: To answer your question, yes, there is. But can you show us what have you done so far?

Comment: try {
    do {
     Thread.sleep(Integer.parseInt(UtilitiesGlobals.OneHOUR);
     publishProgress();
    } while (RUNNING);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
like this ..

Comment: This seems to be already answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562757/alarmmanager-android-every-day