# I want to generate android notification or alarm every day

Tags: android, datetime, push-notification, android-notifications, background-process

In my application i need to deploy a some kind of reminder. that every day at any fixed time my application generate a notification..

1. and it happens if my application is running or not. (e.g by using background service)

I am able to generate notification, but im un able to create logic to generate it every day. Please help if any one understand what i want. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440251/how-to-repeat-notification-daily-on-specific-time-in-android-through-background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below link and this is work for me.

[Create alarm set on a specified time, using AlarmManager](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/05/create-alarm-set-on-specified-time.html)

[Repeat alarm everyday accurately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562757/alarmmanager-android-every-day)

Comment: will it work even when my application is not running.. mean closed ?

Comment: its basically task.  so task only hit when that specific time occurred. you will handle by broadcast receiver. Please accept this answer if helpful for you. Thank you Happy to help.