# Toast message at fix time daily,even when app gets close in android

Tags: android, android-toast

I want simple toast message to be shown at 2:00p.m daily even if app gets close.
    Please help me.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 47);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    int MID = 0;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("dummy","sjcdbfsnbf");
            // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
            Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AlarmManager Android Every Day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562757/alarmmanager-android-every-day)

Comment: @Shivangi: Use `Service`!!

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: What is the actual question? Does your code crash or do something unexpected?

Comment: It does not show toast message when i close the app from background.So i want toast message even if app gets close from background

Answer (score 0):

You can use background service for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    try {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


                if((int)c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) == 14)
                {
                 // Show toast here
                }
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, if(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)==2) in this condition it is not accepting 2